# Sum rules for Clebsch-Gordan series

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Suppose just for example $A\bigotimes{B}=2C+D^++E^-$ with irreps $A...E$.
You have a dimension sum rule ($2*d_C+d_D+d_E=...$) and a Dynkin index sum rule ($2*i_C+i_D+i_E=...$). If $A=B$, you get another special rule, but this involves a sign on the irrep: symmetric (here $D$)/antisymmetric (here $E$) under "leg crossing". (All three rules have graphic calculus counterparts making the formula immediately obvious.)
Question: Are these the only general sum rules involving just these variables (dimensions, Dynkin indices, symmetry sign) with no 6j symbols required? (I guess: unfortunately yes, again based on graphic calculus.)